# UITableView - cellForRowAtIndexPath takes more than half a second

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, lag

I've built a UITableView with reusable cells. At some point in my code I need access to a cell at a certain indexPath, so I call

```
MyCell *cell = (MyCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Sometimes (usually the first time) this is called, it may take from 0.5 to 1 second.

What can cause this and how can I preven this?

I checked if

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

gets called as a reaction to cellForRowAtIndexpath: but it doesn't.

EDIT:

I just did another test and it also takes long if I call

```
  [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

Whatever gets called first, does have a lag of half a second

Comment: it would be nice to take a look at the method body

Comment: cellForRowAtIndexPath creates the cell if it doesn't exist, including all sorts of UI arm-waving.  If you only need data from a cell that is not currently displayed it's far more efficient to directly access your data source.

Comment: I know, but I don't need data for the cell, I want to style the cell according to the data. E.g. I have to change the text of a label and don't want to cause a full reloadData just for that.

Comment: If you want to "style" a cell you should only be doing that for existing cells, or those cells the systems asks for.  "Styling" a cell that is not currently displayed is useless (and a major waste of time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `[tableView reloadData]` first, that may force the tableview to load its data. but still, if a cell is not visible on screen, it might not be loaded into memory.

Comment: You were right, though I thought reload data had already been called. Cells were created at a time I didn't expect it.